# How to kill session on browser tab or browser close in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to destroy session on tab or browser close. I tried  this **beforeunload**. but this close session after page refresh.
 I don't want to destroy the session after page refresh. How can i do this ?

Comment: Impossible, it is security feature... you can save state to sessision store with date and if the date is ex. max 10sec back reload from storage

Comment: what session? If you usr SessionStorage it will disappear on close, and stay on refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of http is stateless, so there's no way to differentiate between closing tab and page refresh.

If what you are trying to achieve is to prevent cases where users forgot to logout (destroying the session themselves) after using your web, what you could do is to have a short-lived session (10 minutes for instance) and reset the the session life back to 10 minutes every time the user does something. If the user is inactive for 10 minutes, the session would expires by itself.